# Printed part problem, distortion on upper section containing hole

Tags: filament

I cannot generate the upper part of the solid properly which contain a hole (as in the picture).  The solid part (bottom section) printed well.

[image]

What should I change to print the part with hole properly?
Is it a problem with machine or the design?
I am using Hydra 3D printer.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to be more specific. The current question is extremely generic and could be used for just about any question on this site.

Comment: It would be helpful have a design photo (from CAD or slicer) to see what the part is supposed to look like.  Also how is the part oriented on the print bed?  It is same as the orientation shown in the design photo?

Comment: Do any of the answers helped you to get an answer on your question or helped you come to your own conclusions then please do vote and accept an answer. This helps us reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered). Found an other answer (then the already posted) yourself? Please add that answer (and accept after 48 hours) to share your experience with the community. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the upper part of your print contains less plastic than the lower. This would mean that as the printer begins to operate in that area, the previously deposited plastic has less time to cool.

The distortions are difficult to see from the distortions of the photograph, but I've experienced similar upper, smaller section failures.

You could consider to print more than one copy of the item on the bed, which will require the nozzle to move away from each layer, allowing more cooling time, or add a throw-away model.

I've also added an ooze shield using Simplify3D to create a single wall around the part, providing the same cooling time concept.

If you try these options and still experience a problem, please consider editing your post with material used (PLA, ABS, PETG, etc) as well as temperatures and speeds used for this print.

Your slicer is not likely the problem, but is often useful information. Printer name is sometimes helpful, but I think it's not critical in this circumstance.

It's also useful to orient the part in the photograph to match that of the print. It's apparent in this case that the top of the print is to the right and bottom is to the left. If that is not correct, please advise in edit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a product of poor overhang profiles and bridging. Issues with overhanging features can most easily be fixed by:

- applying active cooling (for PLA)
- slowing down your feedrate on outer shells
- or adjusting some of the more advanced slicing settings related to bridging/overhanging such as:

  - anchors
  - widths
  - feedrates
  - active cooling speeds
  - etc.